# How to interact with PHP via getURL in actionscript?

Tags: php, actionscript, geturl

```
getURL('http://www.google.com',_blank);
```

The above can open google.com,but how to fetch data from server side(PHP) on localhost?

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial

```
<?
$first="this";
$second = "that";

echo "myfirst=$first&mysecond=$second";
exit;
?>
```

Flash Actionscript:

```
var lvSend = new LoadVars();
var lvReceive = new LoadVars();
lvSend.SendAndLoad("www.domain.com/script.php",lvReceive,"POST");

lvReceive.onLoad = function(bSuccess) {
if(bSuccess == true) {
trace(this.myfirst);
trace(this.mysecond);
}
}
```